# writing file content into a http response

Tags: java, apache, file, http

How can I write a content of a file into http response? I prefer to write it to an entity first if possible. I searched for examples, but unfortunately didn't find any suitable working one..

Comment: Do you mean an HTTP request? A response is what the destination sends back after receiving a request. You don't have control over the response.

Comment: I am implementing a simple web server

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. After all that's what all web servers do when they serve you pages. Add proper Content-Type and Content-Lenght (if known) to your headers, open your file, read it and write it your response.